# How can I use cache when loading 3d models in mapbox?

Tags: three.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have 3D models connected to cluster-nodes. When I switch from one node to another, the model is cleared from the screen and the other model is added to the map. When I select the previous node, I want the preloaded 3d model to come from the cache.

```
`
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1auox3f8/20/
`

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll need to build your own cache (a `Map` objetc could be ideal) that stores `gltf.scene` result.

You'll surely will need some functions wrapping up your object loader engine and to create a properly scoped variable for the `Map` cache.

- The first method you need (let's call it 'loadCache', will checks
  first if the key (I would suggest to use the url as a `key` and a
  `value` with the `Promise`) in the `Map` already exist.

  - If url `key` doesn't exist in your `Map` cache, you create a new key in the `Map` cache, with a value that is the `Promise`. That promise will call another method (let's call it `loadObj`) receiving the url and a callback method, and it will call to the `loader.load`. Once `loader.load` creates the object `gltf.scene`, you return the object to `loadCache` and resolve the promise.
  - If url `key` already exist in your `Map` cache, then just get the result of it with `.then`

If you are going to play hard with Mapbox and three.js, I'd recommend you to take a look to [threebox](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox) that already has cache implemented in this way to optimize performance and load thousands of objects among many other features. You can also check the [cache logic implemented in threebox here](https://github.com/jscastro76/threebox/blob/8120e8b534aa08b9dabe7709d82cbc883aa6e990/src/Threebox.js#L592)

[image]

Comment: Actually, I don't want to dublicate exactly the same object. If you examine this project I have created, you will understand the problem. [myproject](https://kulturel.bimtas.istanbul/)
When I switch between nodes, it downloads the model again

Comment: Uff... sorry to say but examine your project will take hours. At first sight I see several serious problems in your code. First all your models are huge (kucukAyasofya.jpg is +77MB!!), you should consider to reduce them because for the level of detail and without textures they are too heavy. Second, you're adding and removing the custom layer each `map.on('click'` call with `delete3d()` disposing in that way all the resources, so on next click the model is loaded from the browser cache, not downloaded again, but it's created by three.js `GLTFLoader`, that takes some seconds due to the size

Comment: I would consider in your case to implement a loader in the background that start downloading the models and cache them, otherwise, at least store the model once downloaded and created by the `GLTFLoader` in the way I described in my reply, which is not to duplicate objects but for caching the first instance of them, adding them to a cache based on a `Map` object where the key is the URL and the value is the Promise to the load method.
Anyway, with the sizes you're managing in your models, it will be slow anyway in the first load.